# Webpack 4 - Loader options based on entry

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, bundle, sass-loader

Is it possible to create a css bundle with different loader options, based on the entry?

```
module.exports = {
   entry: {
      bundle1: './app.scss',
      bundle2: './app.scss'
   },
   module: {
      rules: {
         test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
         use: [
            ...,
            {
               loader: "sass-loader",
               options: {
                   prependData: (entry) => `$value: ${entry.name === bundle1 ? 'foo' : 'bar'};`,
               },
            },
         ],
      }
   },
   ...
}
```

So with this setup basically I will create 2 bundle.css files, a `bundle1.css` and a `bundle2.css`, but I want to pass down different variables to my scss files based on each entry points. So the ideal would be something similar I wrote in the `prependData`, but I don't know if it's possible somehow.